# Number of "passing" paths in football

Tags: combinatorics

> In a football match, $M$ decides to do $N$ passes with $K$ players helping him out, so that $M$ could get the ball back at last to make the goal. In how many ways can $M$ do this?

**Examples:**

- If the number of players helping him is $K = 2$ (say $a$ and $b$) and if there are $N = 4$ passes between them, then the number of ways is $6$.

$$M - a - b - a - M$$
$$M - b - a - b - M$$
$$M - a - M - a - M$$
$$M - b - M - b - M$$
$$M - a - M - b - M$$
$$M - b - M - a - M$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the number of walks from $M$ to $M$ of size $N$, in the complete graph $K_{k+1}$, where $k$ is the number of players other than the one who makes the goal.

This can be done by taking the $N^{th}$ power of the adjacency matrix of the complete graph and picking the main diagonal entry for the row corresponding to $M$.

If you are writing a program, it might be easily done. It might even be possible to give a mathematical formula, by diagonalizing the matrix.

Here is an explanation: http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~m68f11/algcomb.pdf (look at the proof of Theorem 1.1)

In fact that pdf, has a derivation using diagonalization (as mentioned earlier) and derives the following as your answer (see Corollary 1.6 in the pdf):

$$  \dfrac{k^N + (-1)^Nk}{k+1}$$

Which matches what you got for $k=2$ and $N=4$.

Comment: Wow Brilliant! Thanks! If it's not much trouble, an in-depth explanation would be impressive.

Comment: Is it $K_{N+1}$ or $K_{N-1}$?

Comment: @TheProgrammer: Sorry, there is a typo there. I will correct. It Is $K_{k+1}$. I found a pdf on the web with more explanation, which also has a derivation of the formula you need!

Comment: I checked with higher values of N and K. But this formula doesn't hold good. Values for which I checked are N=4 K=3 (answer would be 21), N=3 K=3 (answer would be 6), N=3, K=4 (answer would be 12). I think there's a minor glitch in the formula.

Comment: @TheProgrammer: The answer is brackets is what you are expected to get? If so, the formula seems to work.