# Combinatorics Problem: K people, taken non-consecutively

Tags: combinatorics

I came across this problem in a programming challenges website (link for the problem: http://ww2.codechef.com/problems/FCBARCA ), and I would like someone to help me with my analysis of the problem (to be clear, this is not a "hey, gimme the answer" problem, I can look at any user's solution for the problem on the website... what I want is to understand how to do it properly, "mathematically speaking").

Summarizing the problem:
You have soccer game and you have **K players + 1** (Messi). With the ball starting with Messi, you need to find out in how many differente ways you can do **N passes** (with N>=2) with the ball ending up with Messi. (On each pass, the player with the ball may pass to any other player (including Messi)).

So, my analysis for the problem is the following:

For N=2, you have:

Messi -> Any of the K players -> Messi
therefore, K possibilities

For N=3, you have:
Messi-> Any of the K players -> K-1 players (can't be the previous one, can't be Messi, cause he needs to be the next one) -> Messi
= K*(K-1) possibilities

For N>=4, you have:

Messi -> Any of the K players -> K players (K-previous+Messi) -> K players -> (...) and so on, until on the last passes you have two possibilities:

1 - The second from last pass was made by messi:
(...) -> Messi -> K -> Messi

2 - The second from last pass was not made by messi:
(...) -> K (Not Messi)  ->  K-1 (Any of the K players but the previous and not Messi) -> Messi

And this would be:
(K^(N-3))*1*K*1 + (K^(N-3))*K*(K-1)*1 = K^(N-1)
which is clearly wrong (not even the test case for the problem passes...)

Could anyone help me explaining what is wrong with this line of thinking and give me a hint of how to properly analyse it?

[Edits:]
As suggested, this is a duplicate of [Number of "passing" paths in football](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353173/number-of-passing-paths-in-football)
There, a solution seems to have been given, with a detailed paper explaining why.

---

Comment: Your condition 2 is calculated incorrectly.  K (Not Messi) allows the previous player to kick to himself.

Comment: It's indeed a duplicate, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you change your second case to $K^{n-3}(K-1)(K-1)(1)=K^{n-3}(K^2-2K+1)$, then the sum will be $K^{n-3}(K^2-K+1)$, which works for the second test case but fails for larger $n$, as the below comment shows.

Comment: I don't think that is right: I believe the answer is $$  \dfrac{k^N + (-1)^Nk}{k+1}$$ (If I have understood the question correctly). (This has appeared earlier: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/353187/1102)